# Building a palindrome from a base string using Haskell

Tags: haskell, computer-science

In Haskell I would like to create a function, formPalindrome, which takes a string and returns the shortest palindrome possible with the input string as the start of the string.

For example:

```
formPalindrome “sun” ⇒ “sunus”

formPalindrome “level” ⇒ “level”
```

So far, I have the following:

```
formPalindrome :: String -> String
formPalindrome x
 | isPalindrome x = x
 | otherwise      = makeNewPalindrome x
```

Is it right?

Comment: I guess whether it's right depends a lot on how `makeNewPalindrome` is implemented!

Comment: Exactly the same question was asked yesterday (but it probably got deleted). Probably an assignment or homework. You have to provide your attempted solution and explain what it goes wrong. SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I think your best bet with an effort like this is to start with `isPalindrome`.  Without that you don't have a viable base case and it will get you started on parsing text in Haskell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than solving immediately the problem of getting the *shortest* palindrome extending your base string `xs` (or, if we view it as a list of characters, `x_0, ..., x_n`), you may want to proceed by small steps:

## What is a palindrome?

A palindrome is a string we can read from left to right and right to left without it making any difference. We can express that rather concisely using `reverse`:

```
isPalindrome :: String -> Bool
isPalindrome xs = xs == reverse xs
```

## What are the candidates?

We are looking for extensions of `x_0, ..., x_n` that look a bit like palindromes. We can say for sure that:

- If `xs` itself is not a palindrome then `x_0, ..., x_n, x_0` is one step closer to being one: reading it left to right or right to left, they both start with the character `x_0`.
- If `x_0, ..., x_n, x_0` is not a palindrome then `x_0, x_1, ..., x_n, x_1, x_0` is one step closer to being one: reading it left to right or right to left, they both start with `x_0` followed by `x_1`.
- etc. for `x_0, ..., x_n, x_2, x_1, x_0` and all the strings that look like `x_0, ..., x_n, x_k, x_(k-1), ..., x_0`

We know that `xs ++ reverse xs` is guaranteed to be a palindrome so we are only interested in generating the list of candidates smaller than that:

```
[ xs
, xs ++ reverse (take 1 xs)
, xs ++ reverse (take 2 xs)
, xs ++ reverse (take 3 xs)
, (...)
, xs ++ reverse xs ]
```

which can be written: `map (\ ys -> xs ++ reverse ys) takeNxs` where `takeNxs` is a list of all the initial segments of `xs`. Do you know how to generate that list?

## Which candidates are actual palindromes?

Now that you have your list of candidates and that you know how to detect whether a string is a palindrome, you can remove all the candidates which are not palindromes and only keep the valid ones.

## Where is the minimum palindrome?

Once you have your list of extensions of `xs` which are palindromes, you can simply pick the smallest one. And you're done!

Comment: *Main> formPalindrome "sun"

<interactive>:2:1:
    Not in scope: `formPalindrome'
    Perhaps you meant `isPalindrome' (line 28)
 I got this !!